# Google Maps returning different for web vs API

Tags: google-maps

So I'm sending in the current address via the google maps API:

Tilden Village,02052

I can find it on Maps just by typing in the above. When I use the call below it returns an inaccurate map location. Am I missing something?

```
function showAddress(address) {
      if (geocoder) {
        $('#mapblock').css('border','2px #CCC solid');
        geocoder.getLatLng(
          address,
          function(point) {
            if (!point) {
                            map.addControl(new GSmallZoomControl3D());

              alert(address + " not found");
            } else {
                map.addControl(new GSmallZoomControl3D());
              map.setCenter(point, 13);
              var marker = new GMarker(point);
              map.addOverlay(marker);
              //marker.openInfoWindow("test",{maxWidth:249});
            }
          }
        );
      }
    }
```

Here is the result through Google Maps:
[image: Google Maps REsult.]

[image: API response/Geocode and Map result]

Here is the result from the API/Geocoding:

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the correct place from Google Maps?  What result are you expecting? Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue (and your expected result).  You might want to look at: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/best-practices

Comment: Ok I will add somethings to the post above.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things to highlight regarding Geocoding API request in your example.

- The 'Tilden Village,02052' is incomplete and ambiguous. Geocoding service doesn't work really well with ambiguous queries. I can see multiple results for 'Tilden Village,02052' as shown in my screenshot

[image]

You should provide a more precise search string as mentioned in this document:

https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#geocoder_queryformat

Have also a look at best practices where you can find approaches to resolve ambiguous queries

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/best-practices

- The Medfield Housing Authority that you refer as the correct result has an address '30 Pound St, Medfield, MA 02052, USA', so I would expect '30 Pound St,  02052' be more precise:

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D30%2520Pound%2520St%252C%2520%252002052